# How to have Helvetica or helvet font with lualatex having similar look as with pdflatex?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, sans-serif

Continuing the migration to `lualatex`, how to have the same aspect for sans serif fonts in `lualatex` as with `pdflatex` ?

Is there something I haven't install or is it the wrong commands ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
    \RequirePackage{luacode}
    \RequirePackage{fourier}
    %\RequirePackage{helvet} % is useless
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Erewhon}
    % "font-not-found"
    \setsansfont{Helvetica}


\else
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage{fourier}
    \RequirePackage{helvet} % remplace arial pour les polices Sans Serif
\fi

\begin{document}

\textsf{Exercice}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `fontspec` uses system fonts. Do you have a font named `Helvetica` installed for your system? Note that you should not use `\RequirePackage` in the preamble. You should use `\usepackage`. `\RequirePackage` should be used before `\documentclass`, in `.cls` and `.sty` files etc. [I don't know how much this matters. I just know that's how the commands are used.]

Comment: You could use `\usepackage{helvet}` with LuaLaTeX but you would need either to not use `fontspec` or to put the package command *after* that for `fontspec`. That's because `fontspec` sets default fonts which will override any previous settings (for text fonts). But egreg's suggestion is better for LuaLaTeX.

Comment: It comes from a .sty file, I don't change it each time I make a mwe. Do you mean that Helvetica is a system font, not a latex one ?

Comment: @egreg I have it, but what is the name of the package to load : \usepackage{???}

Comment: @Tarass Why a package? `\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=MatchLowercase]` is sufficient.

Comment: @egreg ok, then the `Helvetica` I found in some answers refers to a system font ?

Comment: @Tarass Yes, quite certainly.

Comment: You can write an answer, or if my question was useless I'll delete it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the usage of `\RequirePackage` I guess you're writing a package, so you'd like it to be as independent as possible on a particular user's setup. I'll assume that your users will be supposed to have an up-to-date TeX distribution, but not that they have the fonts available as system fonts.

Setting Erewhon as the main font can be obtained by

```
\setmainfont{Erewhon}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  SlantedFont=*-RegularSlanted,
  BoldSlantedFont=*-BoldSlanted,
]
```

This can be reduced to `\setmainfont{Erewhon}` on many systems, provided the fonts in TeX Live have been made known to the system's font library; however you have to supplement a font name for the slanted variants, if you want them:

```
\setmainfont{Erewhon}[
  SlantedFont=Erewhon-RegularSlanted,
  BoldSlantedFont=Erewhon-BoldSlanted,
]
```

A substitute for Helvetica is TeX Gyre Heros:

```
\setsansfont{texgyreheros}[
  Scale=MatchLowercase,% or MatchUppercase
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-regular,
  ItalicFont=*-italic,
  BoldFont=*-bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
]
```

If the TeX Live fonts are known to the system, `\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}` is sufficient.

Comment: You guess in advance my next question : how avoid italic and slanted font be similar. And my latex fonts are not systeme-known. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Tarass Darn! I could've earned 15 points more! ;-)

Comment: How to enable small caps font ?

Comment: @Tarass I have no problem with the “easy” declaration `\setmainfont{Erewhon}`. If you need the long form, add also `SmallCapsFont=*-Regular` and `SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}`

Comment: Thank you, without this commands, the small caps were small caps AND slanted. Now it's ok.

Comment: I was a long time ago ;-) Still a problem no bold small caps, thy are only small caps. As you said that you have no problem with the `easy` declaration, may you check on your computer if all combination works, on in this case tell are the files (fonts) invlolved, I will check if they are not missing here.

Comment: @Tarass No, I don't get bold small caps. But nobody should need them.

Comment: I can agree with you and will forget this. By the way, the same `setmainfont` declaration with ` \usefonttheme{serif}` in `beamer` gives all the sets on fonts italic slanted difference and bold small caps : how could it be ?