# Fontspec - Erewhon : what is the difference between setmainfont and usepackage?

Tags: fontspec, bold, small-caps

What are the diffences and are there drawbacks involved in replacing `\setmainfont{erewhon}` by `\usepackage{erewon}`?

In the first case there is no bold small caps, but there are in the second. This is a serious advantage, but are there any drawbacks?

Should one use `\usepackage{erewon}` without optional arguments? If so, should it be loaded after or before?
It makes apparently no differences to the mwe output.

```
\documentclass{article}

    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
%       \setmainfont{Erewhon}[
%           Extension=.otf,
%           UprightFont=*-Regular,
%           ItalicFont=*-Italic,
%           BoldFont=*-Bold,
%           BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
%           SlantedFont=*-RegularSlanted,
%           BoldSlantedFont=*-BoldSlanted,
%           SmallCapsFont=*-Regular,
%           SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}
%           ]

% or
\usepackage{erewhon}

 \setsansfont{texgyreheros}[
        Scale=MatchLowercase,% or MatchUppercase
        Extension=.otf,
        UprightFont=*-regular,
        ItalicFont=*-italic,
        BoldFont=*-bold,
        BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
        ]


\begin{document}

\textbf{Exercice}

\textbf{\textsc{Exercice}}

\textsc{\textbf{Exercice}}

\textbf{\scshape Exercice}

\textbf{\textsl{Exercice}}

\textbf{\textit{Exercice}}

\textsc{Exercice}

\end{document}
```

Comment: One can take off `SmallCapsFont=*-SmallCaps`, it's useless (no difference) but without `SmallCapsFont=*-Regular` the error message is `The font "Erewhon-SmallCaps" cannot be found.`.

Comment: Initialy I had a problem with slanted lookink like italics, egreg gave me the solution here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212357/how-to-have-helvetica-or-helvet-font-with-lualatex-having-similar-look-as-with-p (I forgot to delete a line) and it works until I found that the bold small caps were not bold ... If I use the easy declaration without any optional arguments I still have the slanted-italic problem but no bold small caps problem. How to solve the two problems a once ?

Comment: Something is really screwy. I can get the bold small-caps to be bold and small-caps by modifying `erewhon.fontspec` but the bold sc font is then also slanted or italic (not sure which)!

Comment: I notice that too,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using LuaLaTeX.

An advantage of running `\usepackage{erewhon}` is that it lets you generate not only "regular" (i.e., upright) smallcaps but also bold smallcaps, slanted smallcaps, and bold-slanted smallcaps. (I'll let others weigh in on the subject of whether it's in fact a good idea to have these additional font shape and weight combinations...)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,fontspec}

\usepackage{erewhon}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
Font Shape & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Font Weight}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
  & normal & bold\\
\midrule
upright (Roman)   & Exercise           & \textbf{Exercise}\\
slanted           & \textsl{Exercise}  & \textbf{\textsl{Exercise}}\\
italic            & \textit{Exercise}  & \textbf{\textit{Exercise}}\\
upright smallcaps & \textsc{Exercise}  & \textbf{\textsc{Exercise}}\\
slanted smallcaps & \textsl{\textsc{Exercise}} & \textsl{\textbf{\textsc{Exercise}}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

For comparison, if the single-line statement `\usepackage{erewhon}` is replaced with

```
\setmainfont{Erewhon}[
   SlantedFont    = *-RegularSlanted,
   BoldSlantedFont= *-BoldSlanted]
```

where the two options enable the font's two slanted font faces, one unexpectedly gets only slanted and slanted-bold smallcaps, i.e, no more upright and upright-bold smallcaps:

[image]

A serious disadvantage of going the `\usepackage{erewhon}` route is that you are bound to obtain incomprehensible and fatal error messages when doing something as simple as embedding the table above in a `table` environment and trying to provide a caption via `\caption`.

Comment: The disadvantage is that is sets the font encoding to T1 and that so you can't use an ß, or other fonts loaded by fontspec.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I hadn't quite finished writing my answer when you posted your comment. :-) You've mentioned one of the problems of the `\usepackage{erewhon}` method. Another, potentially even more serious problem, is the inability to create a `\caption` without generating a fatal error with associated message, "Command \nobreakspace unavailable in encoding T1".

Comment: It would be easy to add the command for T1 encoding, but as itreveals the underlying problem that the whole document is using the wrong fontencoding and that more problems are to be expected I don't think that it is worth the time.

Comment: @Tarass - you should really accept Ulrike's answer, since she shows how one may get all four small-caps font shapes without incurring the severe problems that arise from loading the `erewhon` package.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use the package with lualatex and xelatex. It uses the wrong font encodings for this engines.

If I got it right from your various questions your problem is that you want to set the slanted font and that this disturbs the small caps. This is imho a bug in fontspec and I made a report: https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/209.

You can get around this bug by resetting the small caps font (the example is for lualatex, xelatex needs perhaps a slightly difference syntax):

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{fontspec,fontaxes}

\setmainfont{Erewhon}[
  SlantedFont=*-RegularSlanted,
  BoldSlantedFont=*-BoldSlanted,
]

\normalfont\makeatletter

\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{\f@family}{m}{sc}%
     {%
     <->"Erewhon:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;+smcp"
      }{}

\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{\f@family}{bx}{sc}%
     {%
     <->"Erewhon-Bold:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;+smcp"
      }{}

\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{\f@family}{m}{scsl}%
     {%
     <->"Erewhon-RegularSlanted:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;+smcp"
      }{}

\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{\f@family}{bx}{scsl}%
     {%
     <->"Erewhon-BoldSlanted:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;+smcp"
      }{}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
abc {\itshape abc \bfseries abc} {\slshape abc \bfseries abc}

\textbf{Exercise}

\textbf{\textsc{Exercise}}

{\slshape\scshape Abc \bfseries Abc} %need fontaxes

{\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Abc \bfseries Abc} %works always

\textsc{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Edited to show how to get slanted small caps too)

Comment: The extra code "restores" the upright and bold-upright smallcap font faces but loses the slanted and bold-slanted smallcap font faces. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Mico you can add definitions for them too. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer to allow the use of all four smallcap variants. Feel free to "borrow" the table from my answer to show all ten shape/weight combinations in action. :-)